# Testing for generic type in equals() method

Tags: java, collections

I have the following class.

```
public class Combination<E extends Comparable> {

    private List<E> objects;

    // ...

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        // ...
    }

    @Override 
    public int hashCode() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

I am overriding the `equals` and `hashCode` methods so I can easily create a `Set<Combination>` and not have any redundant combinations.

The question is... since my class has a generic type, how can I test for this type in my `equals` method? For example, a `Combination<Integer>` is not the same as `Combination<Double>` or `Combination<Car>`. But how to test for this in the equals method?

Ideally, I could override the equals method to accept a `Combination<E>` parameter. Would a simple solution be to just overload the equals method? For example,

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    // This method will only be called when o is not an instance of Combination<E>.
    // So in this case return false.
    return false;
}

public boolean equals(Combination<E> cmb) {
    // Compare the two combinations here.
    // <code> ...
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution here is to trust the equals methods of the member objects to only match the right types.  You *do* need to use instanceof here, and you *shouldn't* use rawtypes, but it should look something like

```
@Override public boolean equals(Object o) {
  if (o instanceof Combination) {
    Combination<?> c = (Combination<?>) o;
    return objects.equals(c.objects);
  }
  return false;
}
```

This is typesafe and works just fine, and trusts the `List` (and its elements) to have proper implementations of their own equals methods.

Answer (score 3):

**You cannot do that exactly as you proposed in Java**:

1. In Java generics is removed at compile type, so you simply don't have the type parameter information at runtime
2. `equals()` cannot take different parameter than Object, that would be overloading, not overriding

**Similar semantic functionality can be achieved easily.** You should delegate to`objects.equals()` `from` your `equals()` method and that would work if the objects passed into Combination class objects implement `equals()` and `hashCode()` correctly

Answer (score 0):

You're overcomplicating the concept of equals.  Simply decompose the other instance from within the equals method and compare the valid state of each member.

```
public class Foo<T> {
  T field;
  public Foo(T f){
    field = f;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o){
    // leaving off the standard instanceof checking
    Foo other = (Foo)o;
    return field.equals(other.field);
  }
}
```

Comment: You should be using instanceof, and you shouldn't be using raw types, but the rest looks right.

Comment: @LouisWasserman note the comment.  I didn't feel like putting in the standard boilerplate.  If you think it helps, I'll add it.

Comment: It's not at all clear what the significance of that comment is. For example the comment can be easily interpreted as a suggestion that `instanceof` is unnecessary for some reason. Yes, you should add it. Don't leave your answer open to assumptions.